# Value of Möbius series involving $\log(n+1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, mobius-transformation, mobius-function, mobius-inversion

Let $\mu$ be the [Möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function). It is [known that](http://oeis.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function#Properties)

$$\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \log n = -1$$

I'm looking for a closed-form expression of the similar series

$$\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \log (n+1) \approx -0.63\dots$$

I tried to manipulate the series in various ways by using the [Mercator series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series) and asymptotic series of the logarithm and other known Möbius series (e.g. in terms of the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) and its derivatives), but couldn't find a closed-form.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible start.

$\begin{array}\\
f(m)
&=\sum_{n \geq 1} \dfrac{\mu(n)}{n} \log (n+m)\\
&=\sum_{n \geq 1} \dfrac{\mu(n)}{n} \log (n+m)-\sum_{n \geq 1} \dfrac{\mu(n)}{n} \log (n)+\sum_{n \geq 1} \dfrac{\mu(n)}{n} \log (n)\\
&=\sum_{n \geq 1} \dfrac{\mu(n)}{n} (\log (n+m)-\log (n)) -1\\
&=\sum_{n \geq 1} \dfrac{\mu(n)}{n} \log (1+m/n) -1\\
&=\sum_{1 \le n \le m} \dfrac{\mu(n)}{n} \log (1+m/n)+\sum_{n \geq m+11} \dfrac{\mu(n)}{n} \log (1+m/n) -1\\
&=\sum_{1 \le n \le m} \dfrac{\mu(n)}{n} \log (1+m/n)+\sum_{n \geq m+1} \dfrac{\mu(n)}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1}\dfrac{m^k}{n^k} -1\\
&=\sum_{1 \le n \le m} \dfrac{\mu(n)}{n} \log (1+m/n)+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1}m^k\sum_{n \geq m+1} \dfrac{\mu(n)}{n} \dfrac{1}{n^k} -1\\
&=\sum_{1 \le n \le m} \dfrac{\mu(n)}{n} \log (1+m/n)+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1}m^k\sum_{n \geq m+1} \dfrac{\mu(n)}{n^{k+1}} -1\\
\text{so}\\
f(1)
&=\sum_{n \geq 1} \dfrac{\mu(n)}{n} \log (n+1)\\
&=\sum_{1 \le n \le 1} \dfrac{\mu(n)}{n} \log (1+1/n)+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1}\sum_{n \geq 2} \dfrac{\mu(n)}{n^{k+1}} -1\\
&=\log (2)+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1}(-1+\sum_{n \geq 1} \dfrac{\mu(n)}{n^{k+1}}) -1\\
&=\log (2)+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1}(-1+\dfrac1{\zeta(k+1)}) -1\\
&=\log (2)-1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1}\dfrac{1-\zeta(k+1)}{\zeta(k+1)} \\
&=\log (2)-1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k}\dfrac{\zeta(k+1)-1}{\zeta(k+1)} \\
\end{array}
$

Note:
Ths sum converges since
$\zeta(k)-1 \approx \dfrac1{2^k}
$
so
$\dfrac{\zeta(k+1)-1}{\zeta(k+1)} 
\approx \dfrac1{2^{k+1}}
$.